# Solving Maxwell-Boltzmann Integral

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, probability, integration, probability-distributions

I'm solving the Maxwell-Boltzmann equation for nitrogen at 500K and wanted to solve the integral between 290 and 300. I've simplified it until I get this:

$\int \:\:v^2\cdot \:\:e^{\left(-v^2\cdot \:1.07247\cdot \:\:10^{-6}\right)}\:dv$

But the website I use is giving me the result "steps are not currently supported for this problem".
What would this integral be equal to?

Comment: An exact solution involves the error function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function On the other hand, for $v \approx 295$, the exponent is $\approx \alpha := 0.0933$ and changes slowly over the domain of integration, so we can approximate the exponential factor by $e^{-\alpha} \approx 1-\alpha = 0.9067$ and hence the given integral by $0.9067 \int_{290}^{300} v^2 dv \approx 7.89 \cdot 10^5$. This is close to the true value of $\approx 7.93 \cdot 10^5$, a relative error of $\sim 1/200$.

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int v^2e^{-av^2}dv$$
using:
$$V'=ve^{-av^2}\Rightarrow V=\frac{-e^{-av^2}}{2a}$$
$$U=v\Rightarrow U'=1$$
gives:
$$I=-\frac{ve^{-av^2}}{2a}+\frac1{2a}\int e^{-av^2}dv$$
then you need to put your limits in and use the fact that:
$$\operatorname{erf}(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^xe^{-t^2}\,dt$$